# Remove all images from a table and insert it before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML table:

```
<div class="someClass" id="someID">

<!-- Move all images inside the td's  here -->

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" id="mainTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="Images/9.jpg" class="bvz_beeldthumb">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="Images/10.jpg" class="bvz_beeldthumb">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="Images/11.jpg" class="bvz_beeldthumb">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="Images/12.jpg" class="bvz_beeldthumb">
            </td>
        </tr>
        ....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is go trough each td and remove the image and insert it before the table. And than remove the entire table.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and use `each()` to iterate through all of the `td` elements and move all of the images within `td` before the table.

```
$('td').each(function(){
$('img').insertBefore('table');
$('table').hide();
});
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fwj91wcu/)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working:

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/os3885eh/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bvz_beeldthumb').each(function(){
        $('.someClass').append(this);
    });
    $('#mainTable').remove();
});
```

Document ready means that when the document is ready the code will be fired.
It finds all images with class bvz_beeldthumb on the page and moves it to the div someClass. After that it removes the table.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
$("#mainTable td").each(function() {
    var Img=$(this).find("img");
    $("#someID").prepend(Img);//here element 'id' in which you want to put these images.
    $(this).find("img").html('');
});
```

I hope this helps you!!

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like

```js
$('#mainTable img').insertBefore('#mainTable')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" id="mainTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="//placehold.it/127x191&text=1" class="bvz_beeldthumb" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="//placehold.it/127x191&text=2" class="bvz_beeldthumb" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="//placehold.it/127x191&text=3" class="bvz_beeldthumb" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="//placehold.it/127x191&text=4" class="bvz_beeldthumb" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="//placehold.it/127x191&text=5" class="bvz_beeldthumb" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <img width="127" height="191" border="0" src="//placehold.it/127x191&text=6" class="bvz_beeldthumb" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```